# How to restore Keras LSTM state

Tags: keras, lstm

I have a LSTM model, when I process a batch, I want to reset the state of LSTM layer.Then after a few processes, I want to restore the original state of LSTM(with new weight I learned in above few processes) and continue processing. I know I can use `reset_state()` function to reset LSTM state. How can I restore the LSTM state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not very clear what you're asking, but from my understanding you would like to initialize an LSTM with a given set of weights. From the [docs](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#recurrent):

> Note on specifying initial states in RNNs
>
> You can specify the initial state of RNN layers by calling them with
>   the keyword argument initial_state. The value of initial_state should
>   be a tensor or list of tensors representing the initial state of the
>   RNN layer.

I haven't figured out how to add initial state using the sequential model
but here is how you would do it using the [functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/):

```
X = np.array([[[1, 0],
              [1, 0],
              [1, 0],
              [1, 0]],

              [[1, 0],
              [1, 0],
              [1, 0],
              [1, 0]]]
              )

y = np.array([[1],
              [2]])

inp = Input(shape=(4, 2))
base = LSTM(10)
enc = base(inp, initial_state=[])
out = Dense(1, activation='softmax')(enc)
model = Model(inp, out)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X, y)
```